# Java Load first link from google image search - Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Hi guys I need help with my school project.
I need to get the first link from a google image search.

```java
public String nadjiURLPoNazivu(String str) {
    List<String> links = new ArrayList();
    try {
        str = str.trim();
        if (str.contains(" ")) {
            str = str.replace(" ", "+");
        }
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + str + "+400x400" + "&rlz=1C1ASVA_enRS799RS799&hl=en&sxsrf=ALeKk03xEqKmfzIK77mjVPn_T-s2wmETFw:1622395752826&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjezqCU9_HwAhWN76QKHe7cAY4Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1366&bih=625").get();
        Elements el = doc.getElementsByAttribute("data-src");
        for (Element element : el) {
            links.add(element.attr("data-src"));
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (links.isEmpty()) {
        //  MessageUtil.showErrorMessage("Ne postoji slika za takav naziv!");
        links.add("https://previews.123rf.com/images/esfirse/esfirse1812/esfirse181200156/115299132-cross-sign-red-x-icon-isolated-on-white-background-circle-symbol.jpg");
        return links.get(0);
    }
    return links.get(0);
}
```

This code works, but it doesn't get me the first link, every time it loads it gets me a random image link from that search.

[Search is by product name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZNVr.png)

Edit: Also loading is very slow, is there a way to speed up?

Answer (score 0):

It will not load random images every time. It's based on the source of the image. If you see the first image, you can see the image rendered based on **base64** and the second image loaded from the URL. From your code, you will get the first image available with a link(not base64).

[image]

If you want to speed up remove the unwanted for loop.

```
public String nadjiURLPoNazivu(String str) {
    String links = null;
    try {
        str = str.trim();
        if (str.contains(" ")) {
            str = str.replace(" ", "+");
        }
        String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + str + "+400x400"
                + "&rlz=1C1ASVA_enRS799RS799&hl=en&sxsrf=ALeKk03xEqKmfzIK77mjVPn_T-s2wmETFw:1622395752826&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjezqCU9_HwAhWN76QKHe7cAY4Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1366&bih=625";
        System.out.println(url);
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements el = doc.getElementsByAttribute("data-src");
        if(!el.isEmpty()) {
            links = el.get(0).attr("data-src");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (Objects.isNull(links)) {
        // MessageUtil.showErrorMessage("Ne postoji slika za takav naziv!");
        links = "https://previews.123rf.com/images/esfirse/esfirse1812/esfirse181200156/115299132-cross-sign-red-x-icon-isolated-on-white-background-circle-symbol.jpg";
        return links;
    }
    return links;
}
```